# Looping Sharepoint Workflow - update column throws error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I am working on a sharepoint 2010 application where I need to "trick" SharePoint into updating a bunch of child list items when the parent is updated.  What I have works some of the time to update some of the items in the child list.  Most of the time I get an error for the workflow that updates the child list items.

```
The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information.
```

There are three lists and related columns:

- Project - Name (single line of text)
- Project Tasks -Project Name (lookup field connecting to project), Project Name 2 (single line of text)
- WorkFlowControl - This is used to create the looping

Here is a description of the logic:

1. When a Project Lead is assigned to that project a workflow fires to update the projects tasks with the project leader's name (updates a person field).  It finds the first task that has the same Project Name 2 as the Project that was just updated.  Once it sets the project lead it updates the Project Name 2 field by appending a number to the end of the Project Name.  This is makes sure this item is not found and updated on the next loop.
2. When the task is updated it triggers a workflow that creates an item in the workflowcontrol list that holds both the project name and project lead
3. When an item is created in the workflow control list it triggers a workflow that updates the first matching item in the project task list that has the Project Name in the Project Name 2 field. When it finds one it sets the Project Lead and updates the Project Name in the Project Name 2 field.

The problem is the workflow that fires when an item is created in the workflow control list tends to error with the above error and sometimes the Task is updated with the project lead and other times it does nothing.  I suspect the problem has to do with the fact that I am using the project name 2 value to find a list item and also updating that value to make sure it is not found on the next loop. Like I said it sometimes works (updates all tasks with project leads name) other times it only does a few.  Which makes me think it is a timing thing but I don't know.

[image]

Here is a screen of what the workflow that updates the project tasks when an item is created in the workflow control list.  It first sets a workflow variable to hold the project name, then updates the project lead with data found in the workflow control list.  Next it should 'log' that the Project Lead was updated.  Next it updates the project name 2 value where the project name 2 value matches the project name (see next image)

[image]

Comment: So you don't want the tasks updated with the project lead on subsequent edits, is that the reason behind the name changes?  If that is the case, you should add a bool column to the Project list to see if it has updated the children yet, it if has, then just don't run that.  Much easier than changing the name of the item, and then you don't run into the timing issue.

Comment: Since there are many project tasks in the child list (for potentially many other projects) I need a way to find a task matching the parent project name and update the project lead.  If I do not update the name how do I keep the same task from getting updated each iteration?

Comment: You can do the matching through the lookup column name (so you don't need Project Name 2), and then you add a Yes/No field called updated that you toggle in the list after updating an item.

Comment: Ok clearly I am not understanding, but to my knowledge when you do a Update List Item in SPD you select the list you want to update (in this case the project task list) set the values you want to update (Project Lead, etc) where the list item matches the value of a column to a variable (or string).  How would that work using a yes / no variable?  Wouldn't it just update the first item the list matching project name?  Where does the yes/no play out?

Comment: I think your main problem is that you don't have a looping mechanism.  Update item action will only update the first item it finds, not all of the, so without adding a loop to keep looking for items where the project name matches and the new "Updated" column is equal to "No", not all of the tasks will get updated.

Comment: Correct.  Which is why I set up workflows to essentially emulate a for each loop (when a task is updated a list item is created in a workflow list which in turn updates a task...this should go back and forth until it cannot find an item to update). So, this still brings me back to my first question: How would I update a list item that matches a project name AND has an "Updated" or "isProcessed" as No?  There does not seem to be any functionality that allows me to update something based on two criteria.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60559/discussion-between-dan-j-and-wblakenc).